# Yii multiple systems with the same auth roles?

Tags: authentication, yii

Hi i have 3 Yii based systems, something like:

```
sys1.domain.com
sys2.domain.com
sys3.domain.com
```

now, this 3 systems share the same database, same users, and other entities... and of course the 3 yii auth tables.

now my question is, when configuring auth, how do i separate auth rules for each system?

i'm using Yii extension "rights" to manage roles, if this is of any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have single DB for three systems sys1, sys2 and sys3 and you would like only auth table diffent, you can add three auth tables auth_sys3, auth_sys2, auth_sys1 and in config file of each system write configuration or at global place write php logic to make alias of auth_sys1,auth_sys2,auth_sys3 as auth so you dont requrie to make any changes in internal code to call auth.

Comment: i was trying to do that, but the CDbAuthManager uses the same database as where the user model resides... this idea would work... but don;t know how to configure it on yii... any ideas please?

Comment: In CDbAuthManager or just before using/calling auth table related stuff write logic/condition to set constant for auth table name like if(sys1){const auth = auth_sys1} ect..and insted keeping hardcore auth table name replace it with auth const.....

Comment: but i need to use the same database for users between systems... only diferent auth tables... if i set the connection in CDbAuthManager to the connection that contains the auth tables and not the user will it not give me an error...

Comment: this approach worked... i was only needing to load my users from a different database connection.